# How do you consistently migrate a large MongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, migration

I was trying to migrate a large MongoDB of ~600k documents, like so:

```js
    for await (const doc of db.collection('collection').find({
        legacyProp: { $exists: true },
    })) {
        // additional data fetching from separate collections here
        const newPropValue = await fetchNewPropValue(doc._id)
        await db.collection('collection').findOneAndUpdate({ _id: doc._id }, [{ $set: { newProp: newPropValue } }, { $unset: ['legacyProp'] }])
    }
}
```

When the migration script finished, data was still being updated for about 30 minutes or so. I've concluded this by computing document count of documents containing `legacyProp` property:

```js
db.collection.countDocuments({ legacyProp: { $exists: true } })
```

which was decreasing on subsequent calls. After a while, the updates stopped and the final document count of documents containing legacy prop was around 300k, so the update failed silently resulting in a data loss. I'm curious what exactly happened, and most importantly, how do you update large MongoDB collections without any data loss? Keep in mind, there is additional data fetching involved before every update operation.

Comment: Updating the documents one-by-one is certainly the worst way of doing it. What are you doing at `fetchNewPropValue`? I guess it can be done with an aggregation pipeline. Otherwise [db.collection.bulkWrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db.collection.bulkwrite) will work

Comment: What do you mean by the worst way, in terms of performance? What I've primarily cared about is simplicity and clarity, not so much performance, but the data loss suprised me a lot. `fetchNewPropValue` does lookups to a document in a separate collection that determines the value of the `newProp` property.

Comment: Then [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#-lookup--aggregation-) might be the best option. Yes, "worst way" in terms of performance.

Comment: Are you sure you have correctly used `$unset` operator? https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first attempt would be to build function of `fetchNewPropValue()` in an aggregation pipeline.

Have a look at [Aggregation Pipeline Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#aggregation-pipeline-operators)

If this is not possible then you can try to put all newPropValue's into array and use it like this. 600k properties should fit easily into your RAM.

```
const newPropValues = await fetchNewPropValue() // getting all new properties as array [{_id: ..., val: ...}, {_id: ..., val: ...}, ...]
db.getCollection('collection').updateMany(
   { legacyProp: { $exists: true } },
   [
      {
         $set: {
            newProp: {
               $first: {
                  $filter: { input: newPropValues, cond: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$this._id"] } }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      { $set: { legacyProp: "$$REMOVE", newProp: "$$newProp.val" } }
   ]
)
```

Or you can try bulkWrite:

```
let bulkOperations = []
db.getCollection('collection').find({ legacyProp: { $exists: true } }).forEach(doc => {
   const newPropValue = await fetchNewPropValue(doc._id);
   bulkOperations.push({
      updateOne: {
         filter: { _id: doc._id },
         update: {
            $set: { newProp: newPropValue },
            $unset: { legacyProp: "" }
         }
      }
   });
   if (bulkOperations.length > 10000) {
      db.getCollection('collection').bulkWrite(bulkOperations, { ordered: false });
      bulkOperations = [];
   }
})
if (bulkOperations.length > 0)
   db.getCollection('collection').bulkWrite(bulkOperations, { ordered: false })
```

Comment: Thank you for the solutions, they're great! Do you have any ideas, even speculative ones, as to why the data loss occurred? There must be some kind of internal queue for writes implemented in MongoDB that got flushed at some point and I really wonder why that's the case.

Comment: Not really, what do you mean by "data loss"?

Comment: Not all document updates were committed to MongoDB, even though the updates were accepted (enqueued I guess) and the migration script finished successfully. In other words, data from updates got lost in transit somehow.